# Cross reference a monthly reading to a weekly reading

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, cross-reference

I am attempting to make a table in Excel whereby I have stock prices in one column and corresponding dates in the form 'dd/mm/yyyy' in the next column:

```
date  |  share price
```

I am trying to include the conversion rate of USD to GBP, however this is a monthly reading.

Is there a way to copy the corresponding monthly conversion next to each entry of the stock price so that it resembles the table below?

```
date        |  share price  | USD/GBP
01/01/2000  |      150      |    0.6
02/01/2000  |      155      |    0.6
...
01/02/2000  |      149      |    0.65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a named range (say MYrange) with the likes of `1|2000` immediately to the left of `0.6` (and `2|2000` of `0.65` etc) where `MYrange` is a two-column array of month number (`1` representing `January` through to `12` for December) concatenated with  delimiter (`|`) and the year number in the left hand column, and in the right-hand column and matching row the relevant exchange rate.

Then assuming `date` is in A1, in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(MONTH(A2)&"|"&YEAR(A2),MYrange,2,0)
```

where the formula extracts the month number (with `MONTH`) concatenates it (with `&`) with a delimiter (I chose pipe) and with the year number (from `YEAR`) to seek this in the left-hand column of `MYrange` and return the value if found (set by `0`) from the cell immediately to the right (set by `2`).

Comment: what has to be in MYrange? my table columns are in this form - date/USD/share. The date values start at A2, USD in B2, and shares in C2. could you possibly explain the Vlookup?